# Is WordPress capable of handling a search within a search? (carparts)

Tags: wordpress, search

Apologies for not knowing specific terms; please do enlighten me.

I would like to (pay to) create a website which will facilitate the sales of new car parts within Australia.

Problem is the Year, Make and Model can will need to be selected from the homepage.

Then available parts, category options and a search option would then be displayed based of the specific model.

Is WordPress capable of this functionality?

Comment: In short: yes. But how will you fetch the data (new car parts within Australia)? Using AI, an API, Google search or somehow gather the thousands of different databases and systems?

Comment: Thanks for the keywords, I'm sadly inexperienced but can learn or may pay. I would most likely use a paid template and customise it.

Comment: Do I understand it correctly: all you want is to set up an ecommerce solution that sells car parts? Or do you want users to be able to search - as you write in your title - for car parts in Australia based on certain criteria/filters?

Comment: I would like clarification if the specific search criteria is possible with WordPress. The user must be able to select their specific model first from a drop box style system or otherwise, then all data (parts) specific to their own vehicle would be selectible or searchable from a separate search (within the scope of their selected vehicle model.

Comment: a clone of sorts for something like www.pelicanparts.com

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can handle with Wordpress, we implement this type of filter on one of my Tyres based project via Custom jQuery.

Comment: Thanks Sarbjit. That gives me some details to research.

Comment: No problem, I am happy to assist you further.